# laravel exceed dates and between from_dates and to_date how to write logic

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in laravel.

- The present I am working in attendance module.
- my problem is leave application, first I am applied to leave from_date
  to to-date.
- next, I am going same dates apply I through error.
- and middle date applies through error. This two conditions ok.
- but I apply to leave bellow from_date and after to_date.This condition
  is not taken

how to  calculate this condition. my code below please check

```
$keyWithData = DB::table('leave_allocations')
     ->select('employee','leave_type','name')
     ->where('leave_allocations.from_date','<=',$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00")
     ->where('leave_allocations.to_date','>=',$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00")
     ->where('leave_allocations.from_date','<=',$dateE)
     ->where('leave_allocations.to_date','>=',$dateE)
     ->where('leave_allocations.employee',$empdata->name)
     ->where('leave_allocations.leave_type',$type)
     ->first();
```

**Thanks**

Comment: show error in question @ram pa

Comment: i dont Know any errors

Comment: exceed dates how to calculate through error in emp

Comment: exceed dates middle dates are equal how to calculate

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$keyWithData = DB::table('leave_allocations')
     ->select('employee','leave_type','name')
     ->whereDate('leave_allocations.from_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dateS))
     ->whereDate('leave_allocations.to_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dateS))
     ->whereDate('leave_allocations.from_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dateE))
     ->whereDate('leave_allocations.to_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$dateE))
     ->where('leave_allocations.employee',$empdata->name)
     ->where('leave_allocations.leave_type',$type)
     ->first();
```

Comment: i am write same logic.between dates working fine,but iam first leave allocation in 1/10/2018 to 30/10/2018,next allocation between dates 2/10/2018 to 28/10/2018 its working fine.

Comment: my problem is exceed dates leave allocation in 28/9/2018 to 28/10/2018 this condition not working exceed  dates .